# IP info not getting response?

Tags: javascript

Hello I have an issue with getting users IP and location. I have tested it via HTML and it works fine however when I used it in my questions array the response  it returns a blankn. When ever it asks the question Your current location? I want the response to be you are located IP: and location:

```js
let questions = [
  {text:'What is your name?', audio:'music/openmind.ogg', response : input => 'Hello ' + input + '!' },
  {text:'How old are you?', response : input => 'That means you were born in ' + (2017 - input) + '.'},
  {text:'Where are you from?', audio:'music/beone.ogg', response: input => 'You are from ' + (input) + '.'},
  {text: 'Do you eat healthy?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to my data you are eating ' + (input) + ' and that is healthy!'},
  {text: 'What is your time?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Where I am located' + (new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) + 'that is the day!'},
  {text: 'What language do you speak', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to me you speak: ' + language() + '!'},
  {text: 'Your current location?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'You are located:' + (response) + '!'},


 ];

let output = $('#output'),
    input = $("#input"),
    curQuestion;

function ask() {
  let qi = Math.floor(Math.random() *  questions.length); //depending on your needs, a check could be added if it's been asked directly before or only recycle questions when all are asked
  curQuestion = questions[qi];
  setOutput(curQuestion.text);
  input.val('');
}

ask(); //first call

function respond(){
  let q = curQuestion;
  if(q.audio)
    new Audio(q.audio).play();
  setOutput(q.response(input.val()));
  setTimeout(ask, 5000);
}

function setOutput(txt){
  output.html($('<h1>').text(txt));
}


$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    respond();
    return false;
  }
});

function language () {
  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  return userLang
}

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <img src="http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/138/377/fcc.gif" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="ffc.gif">
  <h1 class="text-center">Hello I am ZENYATTA!</h1>
  <br> <br>
  <div class="container">
<div class="well">
<div id="output"></div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Responce:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" value="">
   </div>
  </div>


  

</div>


<!-- jquery for enter key press -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js" integrity="sha256-jrPLZ+8vDxt2FnE1zvZXCkCcebI/C8Dt5xyaQBjxQIo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/s.js"> </script>
```

Comment: That code doesn't use document.write. You need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. Your one is neither minimal, nor complete (and since it isn't complete, it can't be verified).

Comment: @Quentin Sorry my bad i meant the response not the document.write.

Comment: Now you changed the issue...and it is not clear at all what problem is now

Comment: @charlietfl It wont print IP and location from response.

Comment: @JacobMiller If you don't use `document.write()`then change the headline and the text from you post. And please remove the scrollbars from your code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.write only works as expected when the page is loading, after the page is loaded when you execute document.write the document turns empty with your documen.write content.

Comment: As Jacob Miller wrote, he doesn't use `document.write()`.